# is errno STRUNCATE specific to windowsOS looking for its equivalent in linux/mac. using it in implementation of mbstowcs_s()

Tags: c++, mbstring

Is errno `STRUNCATE` specific to windows OS? looking for its equivalent in mac/linux.

implementing `mbstowcs_s()` for mac/linux, following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mbstowcs-s-mbstowcs-s-l?view=vs-2019,
`mbstowcs_s()` returns `STRUNCATE` for one condition, trying to understand where `STRUNCATE` is defined, so that it can be reused properly in mac/linux.

Comment: The string `STRUNCATE` doesn't even appear in that page...

Comment: If you *really* want to use the C11 Annex K functions in C++ for some reason, at least stick with the standard and not MS's non-conforming versions. There's even [a library](https://github.com/rurban/safeclib) you can likely use instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: here is link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/truncate?view=vs-2019

Comment: we can use that but what if it needs to be aligned to windows mbstowcs_s(), in that case looking for equivalent definition or header, so that it is consistent in other OS like mac/linux.

Comment: If you want cross platform code, don't use Windows-specific functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STRUNCATE` is a Windows thing (value 80), so you will need to define it yourself.  On Windows, it is declared in `errno.h`.